If $\epsilon$ is an unit of a commutative ring $R$, then $\chi:\mathbb{Z}\to R$ given by $χ(n)=n\epsilon$ is a homomorphism.
I know this question is quite simple, but I have got stuck with it for quite a long time. I think the problem goes with my understanding of $\epsilon$. I regard a unit as an element in the ring that has a multiplicative inverse, but I don’t know how it matters in this question.
It is obvious that $\chi(1)=\epsilon$ and $\chi(nm)=nm\epsilon\neq nm\epsilon^2=\chi(n)\chi(m)$. Then, there is no way it is a homomorphism unless a unit should be understood as the multiplicative identity of $R$. But it is not the common definition and it is not even the definition in the book.
FYI, I encounter this in Rotman’s advanced modern algebra. Thanks for any answers in advance.

Could you provide the page for this statement in Rotman's book? It seems impossible to me that this is true. If $R = \mathbb{Q}$ , then this says you can send $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ to any nonzero element using a homomorphism. Maybe he meant homomorphism of groups?

$\epsilon$ has to be the identity of $R$. If $\chi$ is an homomorphism then $\epsilon=\chi(1)=\chi(1\cdot1)=\chi(1)\cdot\chi(1)=\epsilon^2$. Taking inverses it follows that $\epsilon=1_R$.

@Tri It first appeared in p.48 as an example (Example A3.24(ii)), and reused in p.59.

@kotori061025 It seems that the author used the same name for different things. On page 30 he called 1 the identity or unit, and you can see that on the same page, in example A 3.1 he clearly use the term "the unit" as the identity element. Maybe the difference is that when he refers to identity, he used "the unit" as can be seen on page 59 instead of "a unit". I think unit in your question means identity.

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

As suggested above, I put my comment here as an answer:
It seems that the author used the term unit to indicate both identity element and invertible elements. On page 30, he called the element $1$ that satisfies $1a = a = a1$ by the name one, the unit or the identity of a ring $R$. In the follow up examples A-3.1, he clearly used the term unit to indicate identity element. Maybe the difference is that when he refers to identity, he used "the unit" as can be seen on page 59 instead of "a unit". I think unit in your question means identity - but you may have to guess which one he is referring to based on the context.
